# Prove conditions for upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In Sheldon Axler's *Linear* *Algebra* *Done* *Right*, I find the proof of definition 5.26 to be insufficiently rigorous. It states the following:

---

$\textbf{Conditions for upper-triangular matrix:}$

Suppose $T \in \mathscr L(V)$ and $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) the matrix of $T$ with respect to $v_1,...,v_n$ is upper-triangular

(b) $Tv_j \in span(v_1,...,v_j)$ for each $j=1,...,n$

(c) $span(v_1,...,v_j)$ is invariant under $T$ for each $j=1,...,n$

---

In typical Sheldon Axler fashion, his proof begins as follows:

"The equivalence of (a) and (b) follows easily from the definitions and a moment's thought. Obviously (c) implies (b). Hence to complete the proof, we need only prove that (b) implies (c)......"

While I do see why this is intuitively true, can anyone provide more truly  rigorous (and less condescending) proofs of (a)$\Rightarrow$(b) and (c)$\Rightarrow$(b)?

Answer (score 1):

$a$ implies $b$ The $j$-column of  the matrix of $T$ with respect to $v_1,...,v_n$ are the cordinates of $T(v_j)$ with respect to $(v_1,...,v_n)$. Since the matrix of $T$ with respect to $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is  upper-triangular, this implies that for $i>j$, the $i$-coordinates of $T(v_j)$ with respect to $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is $0$, this implies that $T(v_j)\in span(v_1,...,v_j)$.

$c$ implies $b$ if $Span(v_1,...,v_j)$ is invariant by $T$, it implies that $T(v_j)\in span(v_1,...,v_j)$ since $v_j\in (v_1,...,v_j)$